# Ruby RSS/Atom processor that knows which items I have already processed in the feed

Tags: ruby, rss

Is there a ruby class or project that processes RSS/Atom feeds and keeps a track of the items I have already processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2008/12/7/ruby_on_rails_feedrss_aggregator/

It is Rails, as opposed to pure Ruby, but then you need some sort of datastore to keep track of already processed items, and ActiveRecord in Rails is as good for that as anything.

Comment: It would be super cool if that did a HEAD request before the GET to see if it's changed